# how To Select with group by and order by clause?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I need to select from table by using group by clause and then order by clause

```
 select id,EXID,Rate,Date,Currency from tb_exchange where    Boolean='True' group by id,EXID,Rate,Date,Currency ORDER BY id DESC
```

But it return normally like

```
 select * from tb_exchange where Boolean='True' ORDER BY id DESC
```

I need to return the newest item first and it groups by currency name. My Currency Name are (THB and USD )

Please help me,

thank in advance.

Comment: Please show sample table input data, and then show the output you expect from the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
SELECT id, EXID, Rate, Date, Currency
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Currency ORDER BY Date DESC) rn
    FROM tb_exchange
    WHERE Boolean = 'True'
) t
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

This answer assumes that you want the latest record from each `Currency` group and that the `Date` column records how recent or old a given record is.

Comment: This is a good idea, but it is not suppporting to my resean. I need to return all rows where Boolean='True' and the newest Recode appear as the first row in datagridview and it groups by Currency